# Why do we need swap in reverse STL implementation? Accelerated C++ (ques 8.4)

Tags: c++, stl, accelerated-c++

I am trying to answer the question:
Why did we call swap rather than exchange the values of `*first` and `*last` in the implementation of reverse function? Here is the reverse function:

```
template <class BiDirectionalIterator>
void reverse(BiDirectionalIterator first, BiDirectionalIterator last)
{
    while(first < last) {
        --last;
        if(first != last) {
            swap(*first++, *last);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to clear my understanding here. I tried exchanging `*first` and `*last` directly:

```
template <class Bi>
void incorrect_reverse(Bi first, Bi last)
{
    while(first < last) {
        --last;
        if(first != last) {
            //here tmp and first both point to the same thing
            Bi tmp = first;
            *first = *last;
            *last = *tmp;
            first++;
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that this did not work. Then I tried `Bi tmp = *first` to get the  **value**  of `first` but get a compiler error. Is there not way than calling the `swap` function that I can do this? I am looking for way to do it in the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value `*first` as your temporary storage, not the iterator `first`.

```
auto tmp = *first;
*first = *last;
*last = tmp;
first++;
```

Otherwise you are overwriting `*first` without storing its previous value, and so you are essentially just copying from `*last` to `*first` (and then redundantly copying it back again), instead of swapping.

The reason you got an error when you did this:

```
Bi tmp = *first
```

Is because `Bi` is the type of the iterator, not the type of the value you are trying to swap. To get the correct type, you can just use `auto` like I did above, or you can be more explicit:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<Bi>::value_type tmp = *first;
```